# How to awake thread if 2 other threads called signalAll?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization

I have 2 worker threads, and 1 processing thread.

When the processing thread is trying to process something and worker threads are doing their job, the processing thread should wait, and awake when all job done in worker threads is done.

How can i awake this thread? I will try to demonstrate what i mean in this pseudo code

```
class Worker{
      /... variables ../
     private final Condition condition;
     public Worker(Condition condition){
        // constructor
     } 

     public void start(){
        Thread thread = new Thread(this::run);
        thread.start();
     }

     private void run(){
        try{
            ...
            condition.signalAll();    
        }
     }
}
```

and the processing thread something like

```
      class Processing{
          private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
          private final Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
          public void start(){
    
            Worker worker1 = new Worker(condition);
            Worker worket2 = new Worker(condition);
            worker1.start();
            worker2.start();
    
            // some code //
            while( // some flag indicating that workers are doing something){
                condition.await();
            }
            // this should be processed only after both worker1 and worker2 called signalAll
         }
   }
```

Is something like this possible? For thread to wait untill multiple sources called notifyAll() and not just once. I hope i constructed this question clear.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is something like this possible? For thread to wait untill multiple
> sources called notifyAll() **and not just once.**

Yes, you can use for instance a [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html):

> **A synchronization aid that allows a set of threads to all wait for
> each other to reach a common barrier point.** CyclicBarriers are useful
> in programs involving a fixed sized party of threads that must
> occasionally wait for each other. The barrier is called cyclic because
> it can be re-used after the waiting threads are released. A
> CyclicBarrier supports an optional Runnable command that is run once
> per barrier point, after the last thread in the party arrives, but
> before any threads are released. This barrier action is useful for
> updating shared-state before any of the parties continue.

Worth nothing that the `CyclicBarrier` can be reused multiple times unlike the [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

> A synchronization aid that allows one or more threads to wait until a
> set of operations being performed in other threads completes. A
> CountDownLatch is initialized with a given count. The await methods
> block until the current count reaches zero due to invocations of the
> countDown() method, after which all waiting threads are released and
> any subsequent invocations of await return immediately. **This is a
> one-shot phenomenon -- the count cannot be reset. If you need a
> version that resets the count, consider using a CyclicBarrier.**

```
class Worker{
      /... variables ../
     private final CyclicBarrier barrier;
     public Worker(CyclicBarrier condition){
        // constructor
     } 

     public void start(){
        Thread thread = new Thread(this::run);
        thread.start();
     }

     private void run(){
         try {
             ...
             barrier.await();
         } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
            // Do Something
       }
     }
 }
```

and

```
      class Processing{
          final int total_threads = 3;
          CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(total_threads);
          public void start(){
    
            Worker worker1 = new Worker(barrier);
            Worker worker2 = new Worker(barrier);
            worker1.start();
            worker2.start();
    
            // some code //
            try {
               barrier.await();
           } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
              // Do Something
           }
   }
```

In this example, the *master* thread waits for the `worker1` and `worker2` to call the barrier, after which all of the three threads resume their work.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `CountDownLatch` to implement that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use Condition (this isn't so simple, btw https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrent-locks#working-with-conditions) for such simple case. There is a couple of other trivial options:

1. Define your worker to be a thread:

```
    class Worker extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            ...
        } 
    }
```

and use old good .join() in your Processor to wait both threads to be finished:

```
   class Processing {
       public void start() throws Exception {
           Worker worker1 = new Worker(condition);
           Worker worket2 = new Worker(condition);
           worker1.start();
           worker2.start();
           
           worker1.join();
           worker2.join();
           // this will be processed only after both worker1 and worker2 have their run() finished
        }
   }
```

2. Use CountDownLatch:

```
    class Worker {
        private final CountDownLatch latch;
    
        public Worker(CountDownLatch latch) {
            this.latch = latch;
        }
    
        private void run() {
            try {
             ...
            } finally {
               latch.countDown();
            }
        }
    }
    
    class Processing {
        public void start() throws Exception {
            CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);
            Worker worker1 = new Worker(latch);
            Worker worket2 = new Worker(latch);
            worker1.start();
            worker2.start();
            
            latch.await();
    
            // this will be processed only after both worker1 and worker2 called countDown()
        }
    }
```

Of course, you can use CyclicBarrier, but why you need such reusable thing? You even can use Phaser https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html, but this is, imo, overengineering as well :)

Comment: "For thread to wait untill multiple sources called notifyAll() and not just once." I extrapolated that threads might be calling multiple times the await, but I might be wrong

Comment: @dreamcrash I agree, this particular phrase doesn't seem to be clear enough, especially in the context of such one action/phase code sample

Answer (score 0):

Use two conditions and let the processing thread await them both.